# Выбор видеокарты для обучения сверточных сетей

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, машинное-зрение

Есть длительная задача на работу с изображениями 500х500х3. Финансы сильно ограничены, хочу определиться с видеокартой, т.к. на процессоре процесс обучения исчисляется часами. Просьба такая, могли бы вы прогнать сверточную нейронку в 500 сгенерированных изображений через CNN на своей видеокарте и сказать сколько длится одна эпоха обучения и модель вашей карты. Код полностью рабочий, данные ниоткуда тянуть не нужно! Заранее спасибо!

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from keras.layers import Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential
import os


os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

x = default_rng(42).random((500,500,500,3))
y = [[np.random.randint(25,50) for i in range(500)],[np.random.randint(40,200) for i in range(500)]]
y = np.array(y)
y = np.reshape(y,(500, 2))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape=(500,500,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error','mse'])
model.fit(x,y, batch_size=50, epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ознакомьтесь с бесплатной платформой [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/?utm_source=scs-index). Вероятно, она вам подойдёт.

> Colab позволяет писать и исполнять Python код в браузере, причём код будет выполняться на выделенной машине с доступом к её GPU.

Comment: Вот что дает бесплатный google.colab "Сеанс прекращен, так как объем ОЗУ полностью исчерпан". Именно поэтому я и задал вопрос.

Comment: @Евгений Если вы действительно ограничены в финансах, и видеокарта вам нужна только для этой задачи, то - как вариант - присмотритесь к платной подписке. По ней выделят больше ресурсов. Хотя, конечно, странно, что 12 Гб ОЗУ вам не хватило. Может, в этом случае стоит поработать над кодом...

Comment: Если выбрать в Google Colab в настройках среды ускоритель T4 GPU, то код отрабатывает, на эпоху уходит 7 секунд.